# Is it wise to add plugins to the Object Cache?

Tags: plugins, plugin-w3-total-cache

My WP site relies heavily on plugins that our readers can interact with, for example a Buzzfeed-like quiz plugin that puts heavy loads on my server. I use W3 Total Cache to minimise that server load. When checking the Object Cache options, I noticed that by default, plugins are excluded from the Object Cache.

What happens if I add plugins to the Object cache? Will it further decrease the server load? What are the downsides?

Comment: there is no such thing as "plugins are excluded from object cache", and even if anyone wanted such functionality he could not have achieved it.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, I'm really no expert, but when you go to W3 Settings > Object Cache > Advanced, there is the field "non persistent groups", which are described as "Groups that should not be cached". Plugins are in there, next to "comments" and "count"

Comment: well, W3TC is theoretically off-topic here and you better ask the support, but groups here are logical grouping of items in the cache. Comment and count make sence but no idea what "plugins" might be, most likely it is something related to administering the plugins, not to their operation